Smallest ensemble of sets stable by any intersections and finite union
Let $E$ be a set, and let $S$ be any set of subsets of $E$, such that $S$ contains the empty set. Can you identify the smallest set of subsets $T$ of $E$ such that $T$ contains all elements of $S$, and $T$ is stable by both finite union and by any intersections ? If possible write the generic form of an element of $T$ by using elements of $S$, with unions and intersections.

This is just the dual of how a subbase generates a topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition

Do you have a response to the answer below?

$T$ is the set (say $S^\ast$) of all intersections of finite unions of elements of $S$.
Indeed, clearly $T\supseteq S^\ast$. It is also clear that $S^\ast$ is closed wrt to intersections. Finally, $S^\ast$ is closed wrt to finite unions, because
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^n\bigcap_{i_j\in I_j}A_{i_j,j}
=\bigcap_{(i_1,\dots,i_n)\in I_1\times\cdots\times I_n}\,\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{i_j,j}$$
for any sets $A_{i,j}$ and any index sets $I_j$ -- use now the displayed identity for the case when each of the $A_{i,j}$'s is the union of finitely many elements of $S$, and the fact that finite unions of finite unions of sets are finite unions of sets.

Cf. conversion to the conjunctive normal form and the disjunctive normal form.

The question asks for finite unions, but arbitrary intersections, not just finite intersections. So the correct answer is that $T$ is the set of arbitrary intersections of finite unions of elements of $S$; you can't do that with unions of intersections.

@EmilJeřábek : Oops! I did not pay enough attention to the question. This is now fixed. Thank you for your comment.
